# Trying to show equivalence between Metric Topology and Product topology in a certain case

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, product-space

I need a little help with the following problem:

Suppose $\left\{ \left(X_{n},d_{n}\right)\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
  is a family of metric spaces such that $d_{n}$ is upper-bounded by $1$ for all $n$. I'm trying to show the metric defined on $\prod X_{n}$
  by $$d\left(\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}\right)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}d\left(x_{n},y_{n}\right)}$$
  induces the product topology on $\prod X_{n}$. What I need to in order to finish is to show that given an $\varepsilon-ball$
  $B\left(\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\varepsilon\right)$
  with the given metric for each point $\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in the ball 
  there is a basis element of the product topology $V$ such that: $$\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in V\subseteq B\left(\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\varepsilon\right)$$
I've messed around trying to define such a basis element but I haven't managed to do that. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n_0$ large enough so that $2^{-n_0} < \epsilon/2$. For $i=1,...,n_0$ let
$U_i = B(y_i, \frac{\epsilon}{2 n_0})$ be the open ball around $y_i$ in coordinate space $X_n$ with metric $d_n$. Finally, let
$$V = U_1\times\ldots\times U_{n_0}\times X_{n_0+1}\times X_{n_0+2}\times\ldots$$
be a nbhd of $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in the products space. I claim that $V \subset B((y_n)_{n=1}^\infty, \epsilon)$.

If $(x_n)\in V$, then $d((x_n),(y_n))\le\sum_{i=1}^{n_0} \frac{\epsilon}{2 n_0} + \sum_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty} 2^{-i} \le n_0\frac{\epsilon}{2n_0} + 2^{-n_0} < \epsilon$.

Comment: There's a bit of a problem here since the purpose was to find a box around $\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ contained within $B\left(\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\varepsilon\right)$, if you are able of doing that for an arbitrary point $\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that gives the openness of the ball in the product topology.
What you found is a box which is contained within $B\left(\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\varepsilon\right)$.

Comment: I believe I managed to solve the problem though by I taking a similar $n_{0}$ and taking $U_{i}=B\left(y_{i},\delta\right)\cup B\left(x_{i},\delta\right)$ with $\delta=\frac{\left(\varepsilon-2^{-n_{0}}\right)}{\left(1-2^{-n_{0}}\right)}$. This seems to ensure that $\left(y_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is in the box and also that the box is contained within the ball.

Comment: IN any metric space, if we have a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ and a point $y\in B(x,\epsilon)$, then there always exist a ball centered at $y$ and contained in $B(x,\epsilon)$. That is $y\in B(y,\delta)\in B(x,\epsilon)$, for some $\delta>0$. So it is without loss of generality, to assume that we are have a ball around point $y$.